# Roughness of the Surface and the time that a toy hovercraft hovers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

My question is about a toy CD hovercraft. I want to know that how does the time that the hovercraft hovers scale with roughness of the surface?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "hovercraft" you mean something that floats on a cushion of air within millimeters of the floor or whatever it is hovering on, right? Then it all depends on the seal around the edges. The more air that gets out, the more power it takes to refill the air cushion, so the shorter the battery life.

Comment: A little more detail would be useful here. Particulars of the device in question.